# Export Prometheus client metrics from a different server

Tags: python, flask, prometheus

I have a Python flask app that exposes a few custom prometheus metrics, however I want to serve them on a different port, the app runs on say port 8000, The metrics of the app need to be scraped from port 8080, Here is a simplified version of what I have tried so far

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
import app2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    app2.visit_count.inc()
    return "Home"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=8000)
```

app2.py

```
from flask import Flask,Response
import prometheus_client
from prometheus_client import Gauge

visit_count = Gauge("visitor_count","Number of visits");

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/metrics')
def visits():
    return Response(prometheus_client.generate_latest(),mimetype='text/plain');

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=8080)
```

However my visit count remains zero, I have checked by printing the ._value field that the counter is getting incremented but I am not seeing the result.

localhost:8080/metrics even after reloading localhost:8000 multiple times (removed generic metrics)

```
# HELP visitor_count Number of visits
# TYPE visitor_count gauge
visitor_count 0.0
```